# __init__ values vs instantiation value

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I am new to python and kivy, I am stuck at under standing `__init__` with variable instantiation, my code is as follows:

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

spots={}

class spot(Button):
    '''
    classdocs
    '''
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        '''
        Constructor
        '''
        super(spot,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ismine=False
        self.text="X"

class game(BoxLayout):        

    def attachtogrid(self):
        self.m.clear_widgets()
        spots.clear()
        for r in range(0,25):
            for c in range(0,25):
                id=str(r)+","+str(c)
                spots[id]=id
                self.m.add_widget(spot(text=id))
```

My issue is although I am passing id value to text property (last line of code), I am still getting 'X' as text which is default in spot class; and if I remove the default text
(self.text="X") from class the ID text is working.

Could you please clarify the above default values and instantiation differences.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs): # kwargs is a dict containing text
    '''
    Constructor
    '''
    super(spot,self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.ismine=False
    self.text=kwargs['text'] # you need to assign it here
```

Comment: @surpavan when you call a function with arguments and/or keywords. The arguments are turned into a list and the keyword arguments into a dict when you do *args and **kwargs respectively. So you can use them as such.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass the value `id` to the key `text`, it will be stored as a pair of *key:value* in the dictionary `kwargs` inside the `__init__`.

So, you can access to it as <sup>1</sup>

```
kwargs['text']
```

But, if the user doesn't pass an argument `text`, the line above (trying to access to the key `text`) will raise a `KeyError`, because that key wouldn't exist. In order to solve this issue, you can use the `dictionary.get(key, default)` method:

```
self.text = kwargs.get('text', 'X')
```

which, instead of raising an exception, will return the default value.

---

<sup>1: This is the syntax to get the value that corresponds to a key in the dictionary. It will raise an error if the key doesn't exist in the dictionary.</sup>

Comment: Simpler way if you have a default value: `self.text = kwargs.get('text', 'X')`.

Comment: @glglgl you are right. I didn't notice that there was a default value in OP question. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct in a general sense for Python, but they don't explain what happens specifically with Kivy.

`text` is a [`StringProperty`](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.StringProperty) on the [`Button`](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.button.html) class. This means you don't need to assign the value in your constructor as long as you are calling the superclass constructor, because assignment to [Kivy properties](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.properties.html) are automatically handled by Kivy.

For example:

```
In [1]: from kivy.uix.button import Button

In [2]: class TestButton(Button):
   ...:     def __init__(self, **kwargs):
   ...:         super(TestButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   ...:         

In [3]: test = TestButton(text='hi')

In [4]: test.text
Out[4]: 'hi'
```

You can do this with your own properties as well:

```
In [1]: from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

In [2]: from kivy.properties import StringProperty, BooleanProperty, NumericProperty

In [3]: class TestWidget(Widget):
   ...:     name = StringProperty()
   ...:     num = NumericProperty()
   ...:     active = BooleanProperty()
   ...:     

In [4]: test = TestWidget(name='testing', num=12, active=True)

In [5]: test.name, test.num, test.active
Out[5]: ('testing', 12, True)
```

(Remember, of course, that without a constructor the superclass constructor will automatically be called.)

For more information, take a look at the [Properties](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.properties.html) section of the Kivy documentation. You might find the [Events](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/events.html) section useful as well.

You can set default values, if you created the property yourself, like so:

```
class TestWidget(Widget):
    prop = StringProperty('default text')
```

For an inherited property (like [`Button`](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.button.html) `text`):

```
class TestButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('text', 'default text')
        super(TestButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

Comment: That does not work for me. Default values of new properties are not present for the __init__ method of my custom widgets. E.g. for a ListProperty, [] is returned and not the defined default value.

Comment: @wackazong They should be. Note that setting the value in kv is *not* the same as setting the default value.

Comment: Ah, that was the confusion. Just for the record, if you need to get a KV file value you need a delayed init method as described here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/kivy-users/LuiOykPGcpo/PbMCrYbddKMJ